# Обновления стастуса пользователя

Tags: php

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать обновления пользователя, то есть если у него нет активности некое время, значит выкинуть его.

Comment: А вы ведете какую-то статистику по последнему посещению пользователем сайта? И что значит "выкинуть"?

Comment: Ничего не понятно! Откуда выкинуть? С окна? Прекращение сессии по таймауту?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, если вам нужно манипулировать пользователями - то лучше сделать свои сессии в базе + это решит проблему кластеризации.

В таблице сесссий будет last_action_time которые вы будете апдейтить на каждом реквесте.

ну и "выкинуть" юзеров будет:

```
"update session set state='closed' where last_action_time < ".(time() - 60*5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Запулить строку 'last_visit` в таблицу с Юзерами и в нее записывать последний визит! Сделать вычисление по нужному времени и удалять неактивных путём внесения в строку 'user_active' значение 0.

Comment: Раз в месяц делать проверку по этому столбцу таблици, если разница текущая дата минус дата последнего визита больше, например полгода, тогда удалить ее